# toggle kendo date calender container on click of input box

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo Date picker it is functioning well.

On click of icon beside to input box, I am able to open date dialog for calender and it is working.
But I want this dialog should also open onclick of input box..

```
            <h4>Select date:</h4>
            <input kendo-date-picker
             ng-model="dateString"
             k-ng-model="dateObject" />
```

What I have tried :

```
angular.element('#common_datePicker').on('click', function () {
                            var datePicker = angular.element('#common_datePicker').data('kendoDatePicker');
                            if ($('.k-calendar-container').css('display') == 'none'){
                                datePicker.open();
                            } else {
                                datePicker.close();
                            }
                        });
```

On click of input box I am able to open the Calender container but again on clicking of this it should close. It should be working as a toggle.
In this link they talk about API related to kendo datepicker..

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/api

Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Your demo link does not show any content (at least to me).

Comment: Both the links are working fine for me.. Apart from link have you understood my concern. can u help me out ?

Comment: Try opening the first link in an "incognito" window with no session on dojo and you will see what I mean. Glad you have solved the problem.

Comment: yes.. You are correct.. I have not verified it.. thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer..

I did some R&D and find this solution..

```
                // On click of input box of date control open and close the calender control
                angular.element('#common_datePicker').on('click', function () {
                    var datePicker = angular.element('#common_datePicker').data('kendoDatePicker');
                    if ($('#common_datePicker_dateview').css('display') == 'none') {
                        datePicker.open();
                    } else {
                        datePicker.close();
                    }
                });
```

And this is working fine for me.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the JQuery version of Javascript Coder's solution

```
$("#yourDatePickerInputId").on('click', function () {
    var datePicker = $('#yourDatePickerInputId').data("kendoDatePicker");
    if ($('#yourDatePickerInputId_dateview').css('display') == 'none') {
        datePicker.open();
    } else {
        datePicker.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a directive for this...

```js
myApp.directive('kendoDatePicker', [
  function () {
    return {
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('click', function (event) {
          var datePicker = $(element).data("kendoDatePicker");
          datePicker.open();
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```